# How to pass array of objects from view to controller with AJAX

Tags: c#, json, ajax, .net-core

I am attempting to pass an array of objects from my view to the controller with AJAX. The array is not being passed to the controller (the controller action receives null).

### View:

```
    function submitFilters() {
        var filters = [];

        $(".filter-option-checkbox").each( function(){
            var filter =
            {
                FilterType: $(this).find("#filter_Type").val().toString(),
                FilterDescription: $(this).find("#filter_Description").val().toString(),
                OptionDescription: $(this).find("#option_Description").val().toString(),
                OptionSelected: $(this).find(".custom-control-input").prop('checked')
            };

            filters.push(filter);
        });

        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '@Url.Action("Index", "Category")',
            data: JSON.stringify(filters),
            dataType: "json",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            success: function (view) {               
            },
            failure: function (response) {
            }
        });
    }
```

### Controller:

```cs
    [HttpPost]
    public IActionResult Index(FilterJSON[] filters)
    { 
        //...code here...
    }
```

### Object Classes:

```cs
    public class FilterJSON
    {
        public string FilterType { get; set; }
        public string FilterDescription { get; set; }
        public string OptionDescription { get; set; }
        public bool OptionSelected { get; set; }
    }
```

I don't think I'm far off. What am I missing? Thank you.

Comment: Shouldnt it be dataType: "json" instead of contenttype in the ajax call? And if you use contenttype i imagine it should be "contentType". I recommend you check your Http Request. The default jquery.ajax() content type is "pplication/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8". I think you are still not sending 'application/json' because of the typo.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the dataType/contentType issues. I will correct that in the question.

Comment: Sorry my mistake: You dont need dataType as its for converting receiving data to the specified format.But i still recommend you check the http header that the content type is application/json.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    [HttpPost]
    public IActionResult Index([FromBody]FilterJSON[] filters)
    {
        //...code here...

        return null;
    }
```

and

```
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '@Url.Action("Index", "Home")',
            data: JSON.stringify(filters),
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            success: function (view) {
            },
            failure: function (response) {
            }
        });
```

should work

Comment: This did it! Thanks! I should have included [FromBody] from the start.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a ViewModel with a List inside:

```
public class YourViewModel
{
        public List<FilterJSONItem> FilterJSON{ get; set; }
}

public class FilterJSONItem
{
        public string FilterType { get; set; }
        public string FilterDescription { get; set; }
        public string OptionDescription { get; set; }
        public bool OptionSelected { get; set; }
}


public ActionResult Method([FromBody]YourViewModel vm)
{
}
```

Comment: This makes a lot of sense. I've implemented your suggestion. I'm still not receiving the object in the action, however. Would I also need to modify the 'data' header in the AJAX call in some way?

Comment: Well, there are some specifics on how to pass the data. I am using the pure MVC way, so my example won't really help you. Some suggest to user [FromBody] in the signature...worth a try.

Comment: There is a  mistake in your code. The generic list type should be FilterJSONItem, at least in your case, but not in the OP's case. I've edited it.